# Default mongoose _id not incremented

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The default `_id:ObjectId` is not auto-incremented, is that normal ?

MongoDB : 2.2.3 
Mongoose : 3.5.8

**Schema i try to save :**

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true},
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**Saving the created model :**

```
var newUser = new User({email:login, password:password, username:username});
newUser.save();
```

**Server error :**

```
{ email: 'joe@joe.com',
  password: 'joe',
  username: 'joe',
  _id: 51444c0dcc6b4e040c000001 }
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: supinfarm.users.$login_1  dup key: { : null }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: supinfarm.users.$login_1  dup key: { : null }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 431,
  ok: 1 }
```

**db.users.find() :**

```
{
  "email" : "c@c.com", "password" : "hereTheHash",
  "username" : "canard", "__v" : 0,
  "_id" : ObjectId("514447c805a669d40b000001")
}
```

Comment: Perhaps caused by a left-over index? Try running `db.users.getIndexes()` from the MongoDB shell.

Comment: Yes you're right :] I run `db.users.dropIndexes()` and now it's fine. Thank you!

Comment: `ObjectId`s don't auto increment. The error indicates it's an error about `login`. As @roberklep suggested, you very likely had an attribute on your mongoose property called `login` that was set to required and not sparse.

Comment: someone, please write your comment up as an answer so the OP can accept it :)

Comment: Could you please explain why you are trying to increment _id?